# C - Nested loops and stack?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find the location of a target inside of a 1-D array that acts like a table with rows and cols. I could do it using divide and mod, but I am stuck on finding it using nested loops. specifically, I can't seem to assign values inside the nested loop. 
here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int arr[9] =  // act as a 3 X 3 table
   { 2, 34, 6,
     7, 45, 45,
     35,65, 2
   };
   int target = 7;// r = 1; c = 0
   int r = 0; // row of the target
   int c = 0; // col of the target
   int rows = 3;
   int cols = 3;
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
       for (int j = 0; j + i * cols < cols + i * cols; i++ ){
           if (arr[j] == target){
           c = j; // columns of the target
           r = i; // rows of the target
           }
       }
   }
   printf ("%d, %d",c, r);
    return 0;
}
```

The code outputs: 0,0.

Comment: There is a typo in the innermost loop: `i++` should be `j++`. Also `j + i * cols < cols + i * cols` can be simplified to `j < cols`. `if (arr[j] == target)` always examines the first row only. It should be `if (arr[i * cols + j] == target)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with the assignment, it's with the wrong loop and `if` condition.

- The outer loop should loop over the `i`  rows
- The inner loop should loop over the `j` columns
- within both loops, the cell to evaluate is `i * cols + j`

Put it all together and you'll get:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++ ) {
        if (arr[i * cols + j] == target) {
            c = j; // columns of the target
            r = i; // rows of the target
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should `arr[i * rows + j]` be written as `arr[i * cols + j]`?  When `cols == rows`, it doesn't matter, but if the matrix was not square, it does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler arg, yes. Didn't notice the mistake since they are identical in the OP. Edited and fixed, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

Since `arr` is 1D array and inside `for` loop, for any `i` value `j` will reach upto max `3` only so its not checking after `arr[3]`

To avoid this problem take `int pointer` and points to `arr` and do the operation as below

```
int *p = arr;
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for ( j = 0; j  < cols ; j++ ){
                if (p[j] == target){
                        c = j; // columns of the target
                        r = i; // rows of the target
                }
        }
        p = p + j;/*make p to points to next row */
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your 'subscript' calculation — `*(p + i + j)`?  It would be better written as `p[i + j]` (actually using subscript notation), but then it would still be wrong; it needs to factor the number of columns into the arithmetic, doesn't it?

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler I didn't observe that. I modified my answer.

Comment: Hmmm…so I see.  Now you don't use `i` in the calculation, and you still don't use `cols`.  Did you try your code?  (Just an FYI: I don't usually post answers on SO until I've checked the code — or, sometimes, I'll post the answer and then check it, and depressingly often end up changing the answer slightly in the light of the checking.)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would use only one loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++){
    if (arr[i] == target){ 
        r = i / 3;
        c = i % r;
    }
}
```